# How to parse and filter two lists in JSP or JSTL using Lambda Expression and Stream API or some alternative way?

Tags: java, jsp, lambda, jstl

Following is traversing of two lists

Firstly, I need to find whether second list have content whose ID matches with First list. So unnecessarily i need to apply for loop inside first iteration

```
<c:forEach var="mock" items="${form.aktivityList}">

    <c:set value="false" var="ifAttachyExists" />
    <c:forEach var="doc1" items="${form.aktivityList}">
        <c:forEach var="doc1" items="${form.aktivityList}">
            <c:forEach items="${form.attachyList}" var="attachy">
                <c:if test="${ attachy.getId eq doc1.getId() }">
                    <c:set value="true" var="ifAttachyExists" />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>


    <c:if test="${ifAttachyExists}">
        <div class="table">
            <c:forEach items="${form.attachyList}" var="attachy">
                <c:if test="${ attachy.getId eq mock.getId() }">
                    DO THIS AND THIS AND THIS
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Once the value of attachy exists turn true then i parse on second list and display desired results.

The code looks shabby. Could somone assist if i can use Lambda expression or Stream API inside JSP or any other method to handle this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking for Scriptlets. Any other way out for above mentioned situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [1] i do not recommend to try to solve this within you JSP, but there is on other Option, i could think of.

You could create a Java-Class with a static method, which is doing exactly what you want to do, or even adapt already the ouput to your needs.

```
public class CustomTag {

     public static List<> doTagAction(arguments....) {
          /*
           * put your logic here and return a list or what you need
           */
     }
}
```

This static method could than be easily made available in your jsps via a Taglib [2].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>your Taglib</short-name>

    <function>
        <name>doTagAction</name>
        <function-class>CustomTag</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.util.List doTagAction( /* your arguments */)</function-signature>
    </function>   
</taglib>
```

which you than could use in your jsp simply via tag reference!

[1] [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

[2] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm

Comment: I found this way only and already implemented. Thanks for response. Accepted as Answer